# How do I read a dynamically generated HTML radio button value and insert it into a database using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am attempting to create a dynamic survey, in the sense that the user/admin can create the questions which will appear when the survey is answered from the application instead of hard-coding.

My code so far:

```
    <div class="surveybox">
        <ol>
            <?php
            $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT QuestionGroup FROM surveyquestions");
            $unique = array();
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                $header = $row["QuestionGroup"];
                $unique[] = $header;
            }

            foreach (array_unique($unique) as $name) {
                $questionsget = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM surveyquestions WHERE QuestionGroup = '$name'") or die(mysql_error());
                echo('<form action="GET" method="storesurveyresponse.php">');
                echo '<div class="questionheader"><h2>' . $name . '</h2></div><br>';
                while ($row = $questionsget->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $id = $row["QuestionID"];
                    $questiongroup = $row["QuestionGroup"];
                    $questiontext = $row["Question"];
                    $responsefield = $row["ResponseField"];
                    $questionID = $row["QuestionID"];




                    echo '<div class="questionbody"><li>' . $questiontext . '</li><br><br>';
                    if ($responsefield == "Radio Button") {
                        echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $questionID . '" value="Excellent">Excellent<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio' . $questionID . '" value="Good">Good<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio' . $questionID . '" value="Average">Average<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio' . $questionID . '" value="Good">Below Average<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio' . $questionID . '" value="Poor">Poor ';
                        $answer = $_GET["radio".$questionID]; //filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'radio' . $questionID);
                    } elseif ($responsefield == "Comment Box") {
                        echo '<textarea class="questionarea" name="question" placeholder="Enter Answer here..."></textarea></div>';
                    }


                    echo '<div class="responsebutton"> <button class="submit"><a class="button" href="storesurveyresponse.php?ownerID=0&questionID=' . $questionID . '&questiontext=' . $questiontext . '&questiongroup=' . $questiongroup . '&responsefield=' . $responsefield . '&answer=' . $answer . '"=>Submit</a></button></div><br><br><br><br></div>';
                echo'</form>';

                    }
            }
            ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

The code above works perfectly when laying out the questions from the database and inserting all the other required database row values on submit, except for the selected radio button value. The radio button value column is always blank.
I also get the following error on page load "Notice: Undefined index: radio38 in C:\xampp\htdocs....on line 52" under all the questions that load, but the errors disappear after I submit a reply on one of the questions, I don't know if they are related.

As you can see I use the $_GET method to submit the values and my processing code is as follows:

```
<?php
    include 'session.php';
    $ownerID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, ownerID);
    $questionsID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, questionID);
    $questionsText = filter_input(INPUT_GET, questiontext);
    $questionsgroup = filter_input(INPUT_GET, questiongroup);
    $replyfield = filter_input(INPUT_GET, responsefield);
    $answer = filter_input(INPUT_GET, answer);
    $date =  date("Y/m/d"); 
    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO surveyanswers 
                        (OwnerID, UserID,ParticipantName, DateStart, 
                        DateEnd, QuestionID, QuestionText, QuestionGroup,   
                        ResponseField, Answer) 
                VALUES ('$ownerID', 'aaa', 'aaa', '$date', 
                        '$date','$questionsID', '$questionsText', '$questionsgroup', 
                        '$replyfield','$answer')")or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
    header("Location: takesurvey.php");
```

I have looked at related questions and searched on the net, I haven't been able to find any specific questions/examples dealing with this exact problem.

Comment: You are not even trying to pickup and store the radio button value. Start there

Comment: Why have you got a `<form>` and a anchor tag ?

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Vincent.. The $answer variable was inserted into the DB and I get why RiggsFolly says I'm not trying to get the value of the radio button.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, how can I get the value of the selected radio button in this scenario? And the <form> tag was added when I thought maybe the problem was cause the questions weren't being submitted in proper form format.

Comment: Start by reading your error log, then fix the second parmanter to all your `filter_input()` functions to make the second parameter valid EG `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ownerID');`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, that sorts out the Index error that appears when the page loads. Now my main issue still remains, how do I get the radio button value into the database instead of the radio button name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few alterations and finally got it to work based on your pointers and suggestions. I added the get method to form declaration and put the processing code on the same page as the form.

Here's the code:

```
    foreach (array_unique($unique) as $name) {
                $questionsget = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM surveyquestions WHERE QuestionGroup = '$name'") or die(mysql_error());
                echo '<div class="questionheader"><h2>' . $name . '</h2></div><br>';
                while ($row = $questionsget->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $id = $row["QuestionID"];
                    $questiongroup = $row["QuestionGroup"];
                    $questiontext = $row["Question"];
                    $responsefield = $row["ResponseField"];
                    $questionID = $row["QuestionID"];

                    echo '<form action="" method="get">';

                    echo '<div class="questionbody"><li>' . $questiontext . '</li><br><br>';
                    if ($responsefield == "Radio Button") {
                        echo '<input type="radio" name="radio'. $questionID . '" value="Excellent">Excellent<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio' . $questionID . '" value="Good">Good<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio' . $questionID . '" value="Average">Average<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio' . $questionID . '" value="Good">Below Average<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio' . $questionID . '" value="Poor">Poor ';
                        $answer = "radio" . $questionID; //filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'radio' . $questionID);

                        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">';

                        if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
                            if (isset($_GET['radio' . $questionID])) {
                                $answer = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'radio' . $questionID);

                                $ownerID = "aaa";
                                $questionsID = $questionID;
                                $questionsText = $questiontext;
                                $questionsgroup = $questiongroup;
                                $replyfield = $responsefield;

                                $date = date("Y/m/d");
                                mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO surveyanswers(OwnerID, UserID, ParticipantName, DateStart, DateEnd, QuestionID, QuestionText, QuestionGroup, ResponseField, Answer) VALUES ('$ownerID', 'aaa', 'aaa', '$date', '$date', '$questionsID', '$questionsText', '$questionsgroup', '$replyfield', '$answer')")or die(mysqli_error($db));
                            }
                        }
                    } elseif ($responsefield == "Comment Box") {
                        echo '<textarea class="questionarea" name="question" placeholder="Enter Answer here..."></textarea></div>';
                    }
                    echo '</form>';
                }
            }
```

Thanks!